# How to join text from two columns and place result in third column

Tags: excel

I am preparing an Excel sheet for upload to a web site. In the sheet I want to do what seems to be simple; append `.jpg` to a part number.

I have 3 columns:

- Col 1 - part number
- Col 2 - text saying .jpg
- Col 3 - partnumber.jpg

There are 500 rows in the sheet so it's a lot of 2 finger typing to do them all.

Can someone help me with the formula I need to enter in column 3?

Comment: what exactly did you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need column B, you can simply enter:

```
=A2&".jpg"
```

Into B2 and copy down to the end of the list.

Comment: Or `=A2&B2` if you want to stick with using the file ending in column B.